# Overwrite page cache after ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, caching

I haven't been able to find a straightforward answer for this question.

I have an admin panel that shows extra options if the user inputs a password. If the password is correct, these extra options are appended to the page.

**Admin Panel w/password input:**
[image: Regular admin panel w/second password input]

**Javascript that loads the super admin options and appends them to the page:**

```
  function showAdminOptions(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('additional_password', document.getElementById('additional_password').value);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'show_admin_options.php', true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
        // Success!
        document.getElementById('show_admin_options').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      } else {
        alert("ERROR");
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
      alert("ERROR");
    };
    xhr.send(data);
  }
```

NOTE: If the password is correct, the markup for the extra options is returned from `show_admin_options.php`.

**Admin panel w/extra options, after inputting correct password:**
[image: Admin Panel w/extra options]

The problem is, when someone who has inputed the correct password navigates away from the page and then hits the back button, it loads the original version of the admin page w/out the extra options.

What can I do to make the cache save the page in it's state w/extra options?

Comment: this is more of a `$_SESSION` issue than a caching issue.

Comment: @NappingRabbit I don't think so, because if they hit the back button, it doesn't show the extra options. But if they then refresh the page, it does show the extra options. The `$_SESSION` variable is being saved.

Comment: oh I see, I misunderstood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### MY SOLUTION

I decided to just forget about doing this asynchronously, and made the form submit with a method of POST, and an action of the same url. The PHP template then renders the admin options using the $_SESSION variable that was set.